# Expected number of people which have at least 2 objects

Tags: probability, expected-value

We have all $n$ objects distributed uniformly at random among $m$ people. Calculate the expected number of people which have at least $2$ objects.

The probability of one person is $p=1/m$. Given that the expected value is $\mathbb{E}(X)=np$ and the binomial distribution is $\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$, I approached this question in two ways:

Probability that one person has at least $2$ objects is $\mathbb{P}(X=2)=\binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$.

Since $\mathbb{E}(X)=np, n\binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$.

$\mathbb{P}(X\geq 2) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X=0) - \mathbb{P}(X=1)$.

$\mathbb{P}(X=0) = \binom{n}{0}p^0(1-p)^{n-0} = \left(1-\frac1m\right)^n$

$\mathbb{P}(X=1) = \binom{n}{2}p^1(1-p)^{n-1} = n\frac1m(1-\frac1m)^{n-1}$

$\mathbb{P}(X\geq 2) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X=0) - \mathbb{P}(X=1) = 1 - \left(1-\frac1m\right)^n - n\frac1m(1-\frac1m)^{n-1}$

Then $\mathbb{E}(X) = np = n\left[1 - \left(1-\frac1m\right)^n - n\frac1m\left(1-\frac1m\right)^{n-1}\right]$.

I don't know if my approaches are correct. Another solution I came across is $m\left(1-\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^n$, but I feel like that doesn't answer the "at least $2$" question and instead answers "at least $1$"?

Comment: Hi! Your question will probably draw more positive attention if you typeset it using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It sounds a somewhat trivial thing, but it really helps. For example, `$\binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$` yields $\binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. ¶ As for your question, it may be helpful to consider [linearity of expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/). (It seems as though you might have already, but it's honestly a little hard to read to say for sure.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but need to be a bit more careful. I will give a step-by-step answer in a more general setting, but we will retrieve your case in the end.

In a more general setting, there are $n$ objects distributed to $m$ people, and each object has probability $p_i$ of ending up with person $i$. We require $\sum_{i=1}^m p_i=1$. The probability distribution corresponding to this setting is then the Multinomial distribution. For a vector $(x_1, \dots, x_m)\in \mathbb{N}^m$ with $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i=n$ (which represents a possible assignment of the $n$ objects among $m$ people), the corresponding probability is

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1, \dots, X_m=x_m)=\binom{n}{x_1, \dots, x_m}p_1^{x_1}\cdots p_m^{x^m}.$$

It is true that when looking at some person $i$, the probability of this person having $x_i$ objects follows a binomial distribution:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_i=x_i)=\binom{n}{x_i}p_i^{x_i}(1-p_i)^{n-x_i},$$

so that

$$\mathbb{P}(X_i\geq 2)=1-\left(1-p_i\right)^n-np_i\left(1-p_i\right)^{n-1}.$$

Letting $\mathbb{I}\{X_i\geq 2\}$ be the indicator event that person $i$ has more than $2$ objects, the number of people with more than $2$ objects is given by $Y=\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbb{I}\{X_i\geq 2\}$. By linearity of expectation, and using the probabilities derived above, you can find that your answer is

$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[Y]&= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbb{I}\{X_i\geq 2\}\right]\\&=\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{I}\{X_i\geq 2\}\right]\\&=\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbb{P}\left(X_i\geq 2\right)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^m \left(1-\left(1-p_i\right)^n-np_i\left(1-p_i\right)^{n-1}\right)\end{align*}$$

In your case, $p_1=\dots=p_m=\frac1m$ since objects are distributed uniformly among the people, so that

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=m\left(1-\left(1-\frac1m\right)^n-\frac{n}{m}\left(1-\frac1m\right)^{n-1}\right).$$